# VS Code Extension - OnDidTextChange or something like it

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a simple VS Code extension that should take action any time the text in a editor changes. The change could be from the user typing something, deleting, copying form clipboard, anything. The closest I've found is onDidChangeTextEditorSelection but it only triggers, as the name says, on Selection changes.

Is there something that I can use to trigger on all text changes?

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda odd and not very documented, but you can see for instance in this [Word Count extension tutorial](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/example-word-count/) that you only need those two events to be able to be updated about text change:

```
onDidChangeActiveTextEditor
onDidChangeTextEditorSelection
```

Comment: Dead link on that Example.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a real example of this in the [decorator sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/decorator-sample)  and as you will see in `src/extension.ts` you only need

> onDidChangeTextDocument

.